# Have soft-power button "ask me what to do"?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, shutdown, hibernate, standby

In Windows XP, there was an option in the power controls, to have the computer's physical "soft" power button "ask me what to do." Basically, the shutdown dialog would appear, and give the option to Shutdown, Standby or Hibernate.

In Windows 7 Ultimate, the default Power Options applet has no such option, listing only Sleep/Shutdown/Hibernate, etc.

The XP behavior can be triggered in Win7 by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> when the Desktop has focus, but there seems to be no easy way to "map" this to the ***physical soft-power button*** as there was in XP.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I gave up and started using this "System Controls" gadget for that, its buttons are configurable also...http://www.homecookedgadgets.com/gadgets.php?id=19

Comment: Psh, who shuts down anymore? All our machines default to Log Off.

Comment: I got burned by accidentally hitting Log Off today, closed the web session I had open, and my rep. console with witch I was servicing 4 computers.  Outlook having recycled items stopped it. :( I hate that button now, I want to se tit to "Nothing" on click.

Comment: @Unsigned Yeah, but neither of them pop up the Window asking if we're sure, or if we want to log-off, reboot, etc. anymore.  The physical power button is just linked (via ACPI) to the same code the "shutdown" action is on the software 'button'. PS: you can't set the default action to "nothing", nor force that pop-up, via properties. :(

Comment: @Unsigned True enough. :)

Comment: [You're calling the wrong button the "physical" power button.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/personal-computer-power-buttons.html)  Strictly speaking, you're talking about a so-called "soft" button marked with the _standby_ symbol rather than the true _off_ symbol.  There's _no_ way that the power _off_ button can be reprogrammed via software.

Comment: @JdeBP, clearly he has asking about the big button on the case and yes, it can be reprogrammed; even modern systems have a BIOS option, let alone older ones.

Comment: *> Psh, who shuts down anymore?* @surfasb, anyone who has to pay for electricity.

Comment: @JdeBP I have not run across one computer (including even 2002 CPUs that used RDRAM and had no SATA ports) that did not have the hardware, physical, on-case power button's "press" action reconfigurable via software such as a Linux DE's or Windows XP's Power Settings. It's just a button; it's reported to the OS via ACPI. Yes, pressing _and holding_ it triggers BIOS/hardware intervention, and pressing it in situations such as GRUB and DOS where ACPI is not active also triggers insta-shutdown, but when pressed for a short period of time on an ACPI-aware OS, it is **fully handled in software**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, while that option was present in XP, it has been removed (or at least hidden, though I cannot find a way to hack it in the registry) in Windows 7; just like the old, graphical Shutdown screen/mask.

Unlike a lot of the other changes from XP to Vista/7, I don’t really mind about this one because to use it means reaching over to push it then back to the mouse/keyboard to choose what to do. In that case, you may as well use the mouse/keyboard to choose what to do in the first place and forgo the power button altogether.

Comment: I wish, though, that they would at least not have taken away _the option_ to ask the user what to do when the power button is pressed. If it were set up like Windows XP (where you can choose whether the power button triggers Sleep/Ask/Shutdown/Hibernate/Nothing), then literally everyone would be happy.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?
Go into control panel > power options >  choose what the power button does > when I press the power button: do nothing